# Anyone managed to run multiple NVidia RTX 2080Ti cards in parallel with NCCL (caffe, tensorflow) without NVLink bridge?

Tags: linux, gpu, cuda

I am trying to run DNN training on machine with 8x GPU cards. However it appears that RTX 2080Ti cards (and may be Titan RTX) can not be run in parallel without NVLink bridge. Which means you can only run at most 2 cards in parallel to distribute computations. It looks as the limitation seems to come from PCIe chipset not supported by NVidia drivers or P2P over PCIe is not supported for these cards at all (see nvidia forum thread https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1051602/cuda-programming-and-performance/using-multiple-rtx-2080-ti-cards-in-parallel-not-possible-/?offset=3#5337543). On my system I get

```
# nvidia-smi topo -p2p r
        GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    GPU4    GPU5    GPU6    GPU7
 GPU0   X       CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS
 GPU1   CNS     X       CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS
 GPU2   CNS     CNS     X       CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS
 GPU3   CNS     CNS     CNS     X       CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS
 GPU4   CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     X       CNS     CNS     CNS
 GPU5   CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     X       CNS     CNS
 GPU6   CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     X       CNS
 GPU7   CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     CNS     X

Legend:

  X    = Self
  OK   = Status Ok
  CNS  = Chipset not supported
  GNS  = GPU not supported
  TNS  = Topology not supported
  NS   = Not supported
  U    = Unknown
```

```
# nvidia-smi topo -m
        GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    GPU4    GPU5    GPU6    GPU7    CPU Affinity
GPU0     X      PIX     PIX     PIX     SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     0-19,40-59
GPU1    PIX      X      PIX     PIX     SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     0-19,40-59
GPU2    PIX     PIX      X      PIX     SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     0-19,40-59
GPU3    PIX     PIX     PIX      X      SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     0-19,40-59

GPU4    SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS      X      PIX     PIX     PIX     20-39,60-79
GPU5    SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     PIX      X      PIX     PIX     20-39,60-79
GPU6    SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     PIX     PIX      X      PIX     20-39,60-79
GPU7    SYS     SYS     SYS     SYS     PIX     PIX     PIX      X      20-39,60-79

Legend:

  X    = Self
  SYS  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the SMP interconnect between NUMA nodes (e.g., QPI/UPI)
  NODE = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the interconnect between PCIe Host Bridges within a NUMA node
  PHB  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as a PCIe Host Bridge (typically the CPU)
  PXB  = Connection traversing multiple PCIe switches (without traversing the PCIe Host Bridge)
  PIX  = Connection traversing a single PCIe switch
  NV#  = Connection traversing a bonded set of # NVLinks
```

I wonder if anyone got success with Peer to Peer GPU communication over PCIe? What MB do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, NVIDIA officially removed PCIe P2P support on RTX cards. You have to buy the more expensive professional cards to have proper PCIE P2P support. It is not a chipset problem.

[Source](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1051602/cuda-programming-and-performance/using-multiple-rtx-2080-ti-cards-in-parallel-not-possible-/post/5337561/#5337561)